# How to capture output from a non-command scheduled task in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

Given the following snippet:

```
    $schedule->call(function () {
        // echo "HELLO 123";   // nope
        // return "HELLO 123"; // also nope
    })
        ->everyMinute()
        ->sendOutputTo(storage_path('logs/cron/hello.cron.log'))
        ->emailOutputTo('me@example.org');
```

The scheduled task is running, the emails are being generated, but with no content. I can capture output via the `$schedule->exec` and `$schedule->command`.

Ideal end state here is, run a few internal, non-command processes within the `call` method and output the results into a file/email.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just googled the documentation of the class you are using with the words `laravel scheduled output` and the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/scheduling#task-hooks) (Just above the anchor in a red box) states:

```
Note: The emailOutputTo and sendOutputTo methods are exclusive to the 
command method and are not supported for call.
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer got me to the solution, but for future reference:

```
$schedule->call(function () {
        // Do stuff

        // Report to file
        \Storage::append('logs/cron/hello.cron.log', "HELLO 123");
    })->everyMinute();
```

Answer (score 0):

I find it quiet unsatisfying that Laravel does not support running multiple Artisan commands consecutively, including capturing their outputs and stopping in case of exceptions.

`\Storage::append()` from @Chris' answer does only write into the `storage/app/` directory, but I wanted the logs in `storage/logs/`. So I replaced it with `\File::append()`.
However, my log file `storage/logs/schedule.log` is a symbolic link in production environment and `file_put_contents()`, on which both methods rely on, is not able to write to symbolic links.

This is the solution I came up with:

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;

// ...

$schedule->callWithOutput(function (OutputInterface $output) {
    Artisan::call(FooCommand::class, outputBuffer: $output);
    Artisan::call(BarCommand::class, outputBuffer: $output);
}, storage_path('logs/schedule.log'))>everyMinute();
```

`Schedule::callWithOutput()` is a macro that takes our callback and captures all output in a `BufferedOutput()`. It is eventually redirected to the log file (second argument) with `shell_exec()`, so it works with regular files and symlinks:

```php
use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\BufferedOutput;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot(): void
    {
        Schedule::macro('callWithOutput', function (callable $callback, string $logFile, array $parameters = []) {
            /** @var Schedule $this */
            return $this->call(function () use ($callback, $logFile, $parameters) {
                $output = new BufferedOutput();

                try {
                    App::call($callback, compact('output') + $parameters);
                } finally {
                    shell_exec("echo -n '{$output->fetch()}' >> $logFile");
                }
            });
        });
    }
}
```

You can also pass `$parameters` (second parameter of `Schedule::call()`) to `Schedule::callWithOutput()` as third parameter.

If you're not executing Artisan commands, you can write output with `$output->write()` or `$output->writeln()`.